# Use methods as arguments for a partial command

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

Can I use a method with arguments as an argument in a partial statement?

I am using partial and can pass strings, but when I try to pass a method with variables as an arguments, I do not get any results when I click the message box buttons but the parial statements are executed when the tool opens and I get the result(s) without interacting with the tool

```
self.ui.psh_bttn_go.clicked.connect(partial(self.yes_no_messagebox, 'poop', 'loop'))# this works

self.ui.psh_bttn_go.clicked.connect(partial(self.yes_no_messagebox, (partial(self.test_fn, 'Help')), (partial(self.test_fn, 'meeeeee!'))))) # This produces nothing

# Using the following methods

def yes_no_messagebox(self, yes_fn, no_fn):
    yes_no_msg_box = QMessageBox()
    yes_no_msg_box.setWindowTitle("Continue?")
    yes_no_msg_box.setText('This is the message box message')
    yes_no_msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    yes_no_msg_box.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)
    yes_no_msg_box_ex = yes_no_msg_box.exec_()

    if yes_no_msg_box_ex == QMessageBox.Yes:
        yes_fn
    elif yes_no_msg_box_ex == QMessageBox.No:
        no_fn

def test_fn(self, msg = ''):
    print msg
```

I expected the partial statement to work as I am only passing in an condition that should be recognised as an argument. Does it matter that the argument is a partial statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partial(fun, x)` generates a callable so if you want to invoke the function you must use `()`:

```py
# ...
if yes_no_msg_box_ex == QMessageBox.Yes:
    yes_fn() # <---
elif yes_no_msg_box_ex == QMessageBox.No:
    no_fn()  # <---
```

MWE:

```py
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        button = QPushButton("Press me")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

        button.clicked.connect(
            partial(
                self.yes_no_messagebox,
                (partial(self.test_fn, "Help")),
                (partial(self.test_fn, "meeeeee!")),
            )
        )

    def yes_no_messagebox(self, yes_fn, no_fn):

        yes_no_msg_box = QMessageBox()
        yes_no_msg_box.setWindowTitle("Continue?")
        yes_no_msg_box.setText("This is the message box message")
        yes_no_msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        yes_no_msg_box.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)
        yes_no_msg_box_ex = yes_no_msg_box.exec_()

        if yes_no_msg_box_ex == QMessageBox.Yes:
            yes_fn()
        elif yes_no_msg_box_ex == QMessageBox.No:
            no_fn()

    def test_fn(self, arg):
        print(arg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work and just crashes the tool.The yes_fn and no_fn are just variables of the message box method, so I should be able to pass it whatever I want, but it does not work with the use of partial as the arguments for the message box method. Is the line that I am calling the partial statements in viable/correct?

Comment: @PyHulk How strange, I have added an MWE so you can test, if it works for you then the problem is in the part of your code that you do not show so you must provide a [MRE]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the class works as it should, so I will see about incorporating it with what I have. Apologies if the post was not as informative as it should have been, I will ensure to be more inclusive of information in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: @PyHulk If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: I have marked as correct. Not been on for a while,so my ettiquete is a bit off, but I will remember for the future. Thanks.

Comment: Still having issues, but I do not believe it is the fault of the code above as that works fine when called on its own. I am calling this tool via 3ds max 2019 and the python implementation is not great. Having to create workrounds as the PySide2 version in Max is different to what everyone else uses, so when I click the button, it just crashes the program and I have to shut it down. Am looking at the tour again so I can do whats required.

Comment: I did the old "restart computer" and it seems fine now. Must have corrupted a namespace or something. Many thanks.